# Understanding Spring Boot @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I don't understand how spring boot's annotation `@Autowired` correctly works. Here is a simple example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    @Autowired
    public Starter starter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
    public App() {
        System.out.println("init App");
        //starter.init();
    }
}
```

--

```
@Repository
public class Starter {
    public Starter() {System.out.println("init Starter");}
    public void init() { System.out.println("call init"); }
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the logs `init App` and `init Starter`, so spring creates this objects. But when I call the init method from `Starter` in `App`, I get a `NullPointerException`. Is there more I need to do other than using the annotation `@Autowired` to init my object?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'app': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [{package}.App$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87a7ccf]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Depending on the scope of your bean, because a Spring Boot app is pre-configured to use package scanning, spring will create an instance of the bean you want to use. However, just because it has been created, doesn't necessarily mean that it has been injected.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you call the `init` method from the constructor of class `App`, Spring has not yet autowired the dependencies into the `App` object. If you want to call this method after Spring has finished creating and autowiring the `App` object, then add a method with a `@PostConstruct` annotation to do this, for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    @Autowired
    public Starter starter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    public App() {
        System.out.println("constructor of App");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Calling starter.init");
        starter.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Now its working, thankyou. So you always need to use the @PostConstruct annotation when you want to access an autowired object.

Comment: Please see Oliver Gierkes blog post on this as well: http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Comment: @daniel.eichten I agree that constructor injection is better than field injection, but that's a separate issue from what this question was about.