# Springboot fails to initialize and inject the third party bean via autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, javabeans

I have a problem with my config class. The actual issue as per log is :

```
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-10 10:47:47.622 ERROR 10728 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field queue in com.example.taskgenerator.Sender required a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue' in your configuration.
```

I am using springboot with RabbitMQ a queuing service sdk for the first time.

```
    package com.example.taskgenerator;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
    @Configuration
    public class TaskGeneratorConfig {
        @Bean
        public Queue queue() {
            return new Queue("simple-queue");
        }
    }
```

queue is a dependency for Sender class.

```
package com.example.taskgenerator;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
@Component
public class Sender {
 @Autowired
    private Queue queue;
}
```

Please help.

Edit :

Adding my main Class :

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableScheduling
//@EnableAsync
public class FileDumpReaderApplication {

    @Profile("usage_message")
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner usage() {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {

            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("This app uses Spring profiles to control its behaviour.");
                System.out.println("Sample usage : java -jar readerapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=hello_world,sender");
            }

        };
    }

    @Profile("!usage_message")
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner usageTwo() {

        return new AppRunner();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileDumpReaderApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the commandline runner class :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Sender sender;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            sender.send();

            //context.close();
    }

}
```

Note: all the classes are in the same package.

Comment: You might not be having spring-boot-starter-web dependency and where is your main class?

Comment: Post your main class.

Comment: Take a look here for how to setup Spring Boot with RabbitMQ  https://github.com/maciejwalkowiak/spring-boot-spring-amqp-java8-lombok-sample

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my main class :

Comment: @Adya It is not a web app. Should I add this dependency even though it is not web project ? Please clarify. But Previously it was running fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476486/understanding-spring-boot-autowired and use PostConstruct to enable Autowire in your app

Comment: Does it solves your problem?

Comment: Please don't skip `package` statements when you post whole classes. It's critical in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your package --
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.taskgenerator"}) and also give annotation(@Component) on AppRunner class.

You must need to scan you package so that on application start-up they become part of ApplicationContext.